# Vert.x WebClient Http Get returns 400

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I have this very simple Verticle:

```
class PingVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {

    override fun start() {
        var options = WebClientOptions().setSsl(true).setVerifyHost(false).setTrustAll(true);
        WebClient.create(vertx, options)
                .get(443, "https://google.com", "")
                .ssl(true)
                .send { r ->
                    if(r.succeeded()) {
                        var r = r.result();
                        println(r.statusCode())
                    } else {
                        println("failed")
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

And I always get result 400 - Bad Request. Any ideas what I do wrong here?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClient.html#get-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method that you used takes 3 arguments:

- port
- host
- relative URI

So it should be:

```
webClient
 .get(443, "google.com", "")
 .ssl(true)
```

Or, using [`getAbs`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClient.html#getAbs-java.lang.String-), just:

```
webClient
 .getAbs("https://google.com")
```

**Question author update:** *Please read discussion under this answer to understand the full picture. Even though the answer makes sense, due to the fact that maybe question was formulated badly this answer doesn't fully solves it, but comments under it might.*

Comment: Thanks for the response. But both variants you have proposed produces 404 - Not Found status code.

Comment: Perhaps Google try doesn't like requets without `Accept` header. Try adding `Accept: */*`

Comment: that didn't helped me either, unfortunately. The whole problem is aboslutely rediculous coz it should not be that hard :)

Comment: It works for me and other folks just fine. There might something in your environment (a proxy?) that causes this issue. You could start with printing the response body to see if the server tells your the problem. Good luck

Comment: Actually this last comment is spot on! I had NordVPN installed, and maybe it setups some proxy for DNS configuration. The problem was clear after I have printed the response body, which stated some response from NordVPN that those DNS are not working anymore, or something. After removing that proxy thingy, it started to wrk as expected. Still not sure why Vert.x so sensitive, taking into account that pure Java HttpClient, and .Net HttpClient and NodeJS http clients worked even without changing this NordVPN part.

Comment: Perhaps the issue comes from the async DNS resolver. To switch back to the internal JVM DNS resolver, start the process with `-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true`